# Numpy loadtxt skip first column

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to load some data stored in a `CSV` file where the headers are in the first column. I am using `numpy.loadtxt` (v1.6).

**I was wondering if there is a way to load all the columns except the first?**

I know that it is possible to choose the columns we want to load. The thing is, I don't know how many columns (I just know that there are more than 255 columns).

If someone has trick to do that, it would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, It looks like [you can feed it a generator](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), so just strip the first column in a generator:

```
def strip_first_col(fname, delimiter=None):
    with open(fname, 'r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            try:
               yield line.split(delimiter, 1)[1]
            except IndexError:
               continue

data = np.loadtxt(strip_first_col('myfilename'))
```